# How to fix the issue of using php serialize and <textarea> to reserve an array return value when it is running out of the space?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, oracle11g

I am trying to use php serialize to reserve an array and use the html textarea as a transit to post the data and download the array as csv file, the download function is working. However, when an array returns a great number of rows, it kept hitting the error as below:

Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Referer
/n .

My guess is the textarea does not have enough rows or columns allowed?
Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

```
<?php  
$user_arr[] = array($project,$dept,$community,$corte,$pmb,$pme,$type,$area,$officesupervisor,$status);

$serailze_user_arr = serialize($user_arr);
//echo $serailze_user_arr;



?>  

<textarea name='export_data'><?php echo $serailze_user_arr;?></textarea>
<?php 
$filename = "user.csv";
$serailze_user_arr = unserialize($_POST['export_data']);

// download
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

$file = fopen($filename,"w");
fputcsv($file, array('ID', 'Name', 'Address', 'PMB', 'PME', 'YEAR')); 


foreach($serailze_user_arr as $line){
  fputcsv($file,$line);
}

fclose($file); 

readfile($filename);
?>
```

Comment: This maybe one solution https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1201869

Comment: What is the purpose of the textarea, from where to where do you need to transport this data? Why does it need such a round-trip via the client?

Answer (score 0):

We are here to help if you are more clear with question we can move further.
Sorry if it hurts you.
Thanks for this oppurtunity to connect with you